# Existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1 f^n(x)dx}{\int_0^1 g^n(x)dx}$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> Question: Given that $0\le f(x)\le g(x)$, $\int_0^1g(x)dx\ne0$ and the following condition, must $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1f^n(x)dx}{\int_0^1g^n(x)dx}$$ exist?
>   (i) $f,g\in C^2[0,1]$
>   (ii) $f,g\in C[0,1]$
>   (iii) $f,g\in R[0,1]$

**Attempt of (i)**
If $f$ and $g$ have global maxima $x$ in $(0,1)$, we can use the method which is similar to Laplace's method to find the asymptotic behavior of the numerator and the denominator, no matter $f''(x)$ and $g''(x)$ equals $0$ or not. If the global maxima $x$ is $0$, we can also expand $f$ and $g$ near $x=0$ to obtain the asymptotic behavior of them. I have this ideas only, I cannot write it out rigorously.
**Thoughts of (iii)**
Since $h(x)=x^n$ is continuous, $f^n$ and $g^n$ are also Riemann integrable. Moreover, $\int g>0$ shows that the measure of $\{x\mid g(x)\ne0\}$ is not 0. Therefore the denominator of the original limit will not equal to $0$.

Some trivial results are that (iii) implies (ii) and (ii) implies (i).